# load  an aspx page in an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm developing a web template using asp.net and c#, which contains 3 parts.  I handle the partial refreshing of the page with using updatepanel.

As you can see in picture below, the first parts is the top menu which is refreshed; the left sub menu, then the left sub menu refresh the middle panel(Details) and shows all the detail which contains a table with insert, delete, edit and paging buttons. I used a listview to develop the tables.

I have more than 50 modules similar to this which contain a table with some buttons, and if I put all the tables in the same page the page, the code would be very huge. That's why I came up with the idea to put each table in separate page and just load each page in the 3rd panel.

I have gone through the Uframe but I couldn't use it at my page properly.

I would really appreciate that anybody help me to overcome this problem, to load separate aspx page in 3rd panel, but without using iframe, or guide me how to use the uframe step by step. Or if you have another idea to get rid of this problem.

[image: My sample page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the type of situation that Master Pages were intended for. Master pages allow you to define a consistent look for pages, with as much content as you like on the Master, and the parts that change in a "child" page (in the ContentTemplate)

Master Pages are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) and there is an introduction to Master Pages video [here](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=asp.net%20master%20pages%20video&view=detail&mid=31809E683926F3C17DC431809E683926F3C17DC4&first=0&FORM=LKVR1).

Master pages can absolutely work with an UpdatePanel as well.  This is documented specifically [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864.aspx).

Comment: Really appreciate for your quick answer. i'll go through. i have another question: if i want to manage this scenario with using web.config how i can manage this? by the condition of control everything by web.config which means as you see at my page i have some buttons and table, then how i can manage the number of rows of the table and number of text box or dropdown for the inserting part.

Comment: That should be posted as a completely separate question.  But go though the links I gave you first so you have a better idea of what you're dealing with before you ask.